# (only) Suggested edit review items show up in my new toolbar...

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

Since when do pending suggested edit review item show up in my new toolbar?

[image]

And is it only for suggested edits?

Comment: (Off.) I don't have 'float' and 'full width' buttons in the bar — are you using some extension?

Comment: @GrigoryM yes, the one mentioned here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11955/19341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got added as part of a feature request on Meta. I asked one of the guys to help me dig it up: [Bring back review numbers to the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209998/bring-back-review-numbers-to-the-top-bar)

The accepted answer was posted on the 17th, so I assume that's around when it started. It also adds that the item *is* for suggested edits only, but they may roll out a new thing after New Year's that is more generalized.

Comment: thanks dennis...